# Mysql optimization query on 2 tables

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

Let db1 and db2 
db1.table1

```
annee   code    code2   var1    ....
1991    11    12    779
1991    11    14    105
1991    11    15    10
1991    12    11    466
1991    12    14    296
1991    12    15    270
1991    14    11    15
1991    14    12    510
1991    14    15    6
1991    15    11    193
1991    15    12    455
1991    15    14    4   
....
1992    11    12    779
1992    11    14    105
1992    11    15    10
1992    12    11    466
1992    12    14    296
1992    12    15    270
1992    14    11    15
1992    14    12    510
1992    14    15    6
1992    15    11    193
1992    15    12    455
1992    15    14    4   
....
```

db2.table2

```
var1    code    ...
test  11
test  12
test  14
test2 11
test2 14
test2 15
...
```

I need to optimize the following query (because db1.table1 contains 8 000 000 rows) :

```
select annee,sum(var1) from db1.table1 as M where 
M.code in 
(select t1.code from db2.table2 as t1 cross join db2.table2 as t2 where t1.var1='Test2' and t2.var1='Test2' and t1.code <> t2.code) 
and M.code2 in 
(select t2.code from db2.table2 as t1 cross join db2.table2 as t2 where t1.var1='Test2' and t2.var1='Test2' and t1.code <> t2.code) 
group by annee order by annee desc
```

db1.table1 and db2.table2 are indexed and sorted.
Any advice would be much appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As variant you can try the following

```
select m.annee,sum(m.var1)
from db1.table1 m
join
  (
    select t1.code code1,t2.code code2
    from db2.table2 t1
    join db2.table2 t2 on t1.var1='Test2' and t2.var1=t1.var1 and t1.code<t2.code
  ) c
on (m.code=c.code1 and m.code2=c.code2) or (m.code=c.code2 and m.code2=c.code1)
group by m.annee
order by m.annee desc
```

I used `JOIN` instead `CROSS JOIN` and `JOIN` instead two `IN`.

And if it suit you you can try optimize query

```
select m.annee,sum(m.var1)
from db2.table2 t1
join db2.table2 t2 on t1.var1='Test2' and t2.var1=t1.var1 and t1.code<t2.code
join db1.table1 m on (m.code=t1.code and m.code2=t2.code) or (m.code=t2.code and m.code2=t1.code)
group by m.annee
order by m.annee desc
```

The first `JOIN` returns all the combinations for `test2`. There are (11,12) and (11,14)

```
db2.table2 t1
join db2.table2 t2 on t1.var1='Test2' and t2.var1=t1.var1 and t1.code<t2.code
```

And the second `JOIN` checks rows from `table1` on these combinations

```
join db1.table1 m on (m.code=t1.code and m.code2=t2.code) or (m.code=t2.code and m.code2=t1.code)
```

Try to check the next variant, too

```
select m.annee,sum(m.var1)
from db2.table2 t1
join db2.table2 t2 on t1.var1='Test2' and t2.var1=t1.var1 and t1.code<>t2.code
join db1.table1 m on m.code=t1.code and m.code2=t2.code
group by m.annee
order by m.annee desc
```

If the last variant returns correct result then you can try to add index for `(code,code2)` into `table1`

```
CREATE INDEX idx_table1_code_code2 ON db1.table1 (code,code2)
```

Comment: I was considering this. And I do not think it will give the results the OP requires as their original code is is looking for a matching code from t1 and t2, but not necessarily from the same row

Comment: @Kickstart - Yes, I looked query again and I think you're right.

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: I've tried but it takes long time (> 25 sec)... Anyway, thanks

Comment: @user2129506 - Try to check one more variant. I added it in the end. Is the result correct?

Comment: @Leran2002 If `m.code = m.code2` your query can't give right result.

Comment: I think change like this make your answer perfect with join solution `join db1.table1 m on m.code=t1.code and (m.code = m.code2 or m.code2=t2.code)`

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức - `If m.code = m.code2 your query can't give right result.` Why? I changed `and t1.code<>t2.code`, too.

Comment: `m.code = m.code2 = 1`  and `db2.table2` with `var1='Test2'` has 2 rows with code values 1 and 2 -> It is ok for asker query. But your query will eliminate it because `t1.code<>t2.code and m.code=t1.code and m.code2=t2.code` will be false

Comment: @KhánhBùiĐức - Yes, I didn't consider this case. Ok, I'll see. I think your change has a problem with duplicate of rows because we have several combinations where `code1` is the same. For example `11` - (`11`,12),(`11`,14),(12,11),(12,14),(14,11),(14,12).

Comment: @Leran2002 the second variant is slower (29 sec).

Comment: @user2129506 - Do you have any rows in the `table1` where `code=code2`? Is this case permissible?

Comment: @user2129506 - If the last variant returns correct result then you can try to add index for `(code,code2)` into `table1` - `CREATE INDEX idx_table1_code_code2 ON db1.table1 (code,code2)`.

Comment: @Leran2002 ok but I have to quit now fur a few hours  Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161825/discussion-between-user2129506-and-leran2002).

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to make your query logic more simpler. Hope this help

```
    select annee,sum(var1) 
        from db1.table1 as M where 
            exists( select var1 from db2.table2 t2 
                        where t2.var1='Test2' 
                        group by t2.var1 
                        having sum(t2.code = M.code) >= 1 
                            and sum(t2.code = M.code2) >= 1 
                            and (M.code != M.code2 or sum(t2.code != M.code) >= 1))

        group by annee 
        order by annee desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table2: INDEX(var1, code)
table1: INDEX(code, code2, annee)
```

Change `IN ( SELECT ... )` into `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) ON ...`; the former is poorly optimized.

If you are using MySQL 5.6 or later, then the subqueries *may* be sufficiently optimized.  If you are using an older version, create a `TEMPORARY TABLE` with that duplicated subquery.